# How to sort for properties inside an other object in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have this document and I want to sort the other documents based on the `views`.

```
{
    "info": {
        "title": "Hello",
        "views": 500,
        "cover": "https:----",
        "duration": 203,
        "album": true,
        "lyrics": "---"
    },
    "_id": "62bb107c70a37ead49d685f8",
    "userName": [
        "Ben",
        "Mike"
    ],
    "audio": "---",
    "__v": 0
},
```

This is my sorting code at the moment:

```
const song = await Song.find({}).sort({ views: 1 }).limit(10)
```

This code is not working I am getting back unordered documents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the `views` field is inside `info` object, you have to use `{ "info.views": 1 }`. This should give you the desired result.

```
const song = await Song.find({}).sort({ "info.views": 1 }).limit(10)
```

Comment: It doesn't work. The code can't be excited.

Comment: Did you use double quotes before?

Comment: Thanks man it worked with the double quotes. Prettier was removing the quotes.